# Php cannot run procedure on Proxysql

Tags: php, mysql, proxy, procedure

I made my "Laravel" project connected to "Proxysql". Every query works fine (select, insert, update, func etc.) but if I add a SELECT query without INTO the procedure does not answer to php.

If I connect to "Proxysql" via Mysql WorkBench and call the procedure that works.

I tried to disabled all of the rules and also added a rule about CALL but it doesn't work.

Any idea?

Edit: I talkted to Rene from Proxysql, We understand the problem is coming from Laravel but i still didn't fix the problem, what kind of data should i share about it?

[Proxysql issue](https://github.com/sysown/proxysql/issues/1143#issuecomment-323106179)

Comment: We can't fix what we can't see. Can you edit your question to provide a minimal code example to illustrate the problem?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for comment, I added some informations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set in PDO constructor attribute `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` to `TRUE`.
It solves the problem.